# ClaimRequirementFilter - OnAuthorization isn't called

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have implemented the [ClaimRequirementFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41348219/1974344), but the OnAuthorization method isn't called. The next line of code is added to the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class:

```
services.AddMvc(config => config.Filters.Add(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter)));
```

I am using the next namespaces:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
```

Comment: Do you add authorization and authentication ?

Comment: @aguafrommars I have implemented public AuthenticationFilter(RequestDelegate next) and used app.UseMiddleware<AuthenticationFilter>(); in the Startup class. If you mean something else, could you please explain the correct way to implement the authenication/ authorization parts. I would like to authenticate (calling an SSO api in the AuthenticationFilter) and within the ClaimRequirementFilter I want to check if the logged in user has a certain permission to execute a request.

Comment: Personnaly I prefer to use a Policy to check for claims : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: And use OpenIdConnect and Authentication middleware : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: What's your SSO ? I don't think you need a custom Authentication middleware

Comment: @aguafrommars The SSO is created by one of our teams. We are using a permission based strategy, so every function will get a Permission attribute. I don't like the Policy check, because I would have to define one policy for every permission. Could you indicate why the current implementation doesn't work?

Comment: Did you register your filter in DI like sevice.AddScopped<ClaimRequirementFilter>() ?

Comment: Did you add Authorization ? `services.AddAuthorization()`

Comment: @Odrai I fail to reproduce your issue with implementing `ClaimRequirementFilter`. Is there any reproducable project? Here is my test project [ClaimRequirementFilter](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/MVCPro/ActionFilters/ClaimRequirementFilter.cs).

Comment: @TaoZhou Thanks for the test project, the OnAuthorization method is called! I have implemented the 'ClaimRequirementAttribute' as wel, but it results in a System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Security.Claims.Claim' while attempting to activate 'MyNamespace.ClaimRequirementFilter'. Could you point me in the right direction to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For resolving op's issue related with OnAuthorization is not called, share the [working demo](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/blob/master/MVCPro/ActionFilters/ClaimRequirementFilter.cs).

> Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Security.Claims.Claim' while attempting to activate 'MyNamespace.ClaimRequirementFilter'.

For this error, define your own `Claim` like

```
  public class Claim
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And register it in `Startu.cs` like

```
services.AddTransient<Claim>();
        services.AddMvc(c =>
                        {
                            c.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestLoggerActionFilter));
                            c.Filters.Add(typeof(ClaimRequirementFilter));
                        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this results in the next error: " A suitable constructor for type 'MyNamespace.ClaimRequirementFilter' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor."

Comment: @Odrai you could download this [project](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/MVCPro) for complete code.

Comment: I am using your test project, but it doesn't contain the attribute.

Comment: The constructor of the ClaimRequirementFilter is called twice. The Claim object (parameter) properties are null during the first call and in the second they are filled. The OnAuthorization is only called once, using the null values.